# how to get the available capacity of a zone in AWS ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The AWS terminated my running spot with the error "instance-terminated-capacity-oversubscribed"

Is there a way to see the  available capacity of an instance type in the different ec2 zones ? so I can create my new spot in a more "available" zone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "spot instance history". This will not tell you the future, but will give you a good indication up to now.

This link will show you how to use the AWS Console and CLI to get history data.

[Spot Instance Pricing History](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances-history.html)

Comment: The spot history tells me the price but not the capacity and apparently they are not the same . Also my spot was terminated my bid price was much higher than the price in the spot history price

Comment: The higher the price the higher the activity and lower available capacity. This is not 100% accurate as there are many, many factors that go into spot pricing and termination. You could launch on a machine that is totally empty. Another bidder launches 20 instances at 2x on-demand price and voila you are gone. You have to be prepared to be terminated at any time for any reason.

Comment: the only factor I can use to chose the "best" zone is the history price ?

Comment: Correct. Amazon does not provide current utilization details. I think that you are worrying about the wrong thing. Amazon's spot instances are in high demand. You will always have capacity issues that change from one instant to another. You just need to design that fact into your launch plans.

Comment: This is correct.  Spot capacity is dynamic *surplus* capacity, so on-demand instances change the size of the pool.  In November, 2017, AWS changed the way spot market pricing is set, removing the near-instantaneous responsiveness of pricing to demand and instead adjusting it gradually over time.  As such, it is no longer always sufficient to bid more than the current price in order to retain the machines, because the price does not spike with demand, as before.  Still, you will generally see pricing trends that reveal demand trends.  It is the only proxy for capacity that is available.

Comment: is it possible that one of the the allocation parameters is the past user usage? meaning that if in the past I used high percentage of the instance resources I will less likely get new spot request ?