# How to detect if AWS has sufficient capacity to launch r4 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, error-checking

We keep running into this insufficient capacity way too often when we launch our cloudformation to create test environments. I've not found a way to proactively check if AWS can provide capacity to launch the number of instances of the specific type that we want. Is there really no way to check early instead of waiting each time for cloudformation to fail and resorting to using r3 type instances (besides adding more availability zones, i.e. not specifying them?)

Error:

```
2018-01-15T03:45:24.202064 2018-01-15 03:44:34.868000+00:00 | CREATE_FAILED | AWS::EC2::Instance | SlaveNode1 | We currently do not have sufficient r4.xlarge capacity in the Availability Zone you requested (ap-northeast-1c). Our system will be working on provisioning additional capacity. You can currently get r4.xlarge capacity by not specifying an Availability Zone in your request or choosing , ap-northeast-1a.
```

Comment: Though look for pre-check is not an issue, I hope you are aware that you can reach out to AWS Support to increase default limits.

Comment: This error is that AWS has no capacity to even run r4.large. It does not matter if I increase, AWS does not have sufficient resources to let anyone launch r4.large in that particular zone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the available capacity of a zone in AWS ec2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397416/how-to-get-the-available-capacity-of-a-zone-in-aws-ec2)

Answer (score 1):

That's a very common scenario for non standard Ec2 instance type. I'd the same issue running R6g instances, and even worst... those instances on my case were part of my eks cluster... after a chat with AWS support we decide to create a new node group with a different family type so in case of need we will have the capacity in place.
Long story short, you have no way to query AWS AZ directly to check compute capacity for certain ec2 type, the only way to know that is trying to deploy the ec2 and you will have a error if no they have no capacity available for you.
It's bad, I know...